How can I review a query log for a SwiftData operation using Xcode debug instruments?
I am using a filter to select the proper record from a queried table, because I have not been able to get a Predicate to compile with this logic.
let assignmentFound = person.assignments!.filter { assignment in
    assignment.readingLanding == readingLanding
}

Is there a way for me to determine how many queries this code is performing?

That code is run in memory, so none.
